# Get multiple values from summary tables in Model builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, error-000539

[image]

I working with ModelBuilder and  I have two summary statistics tools,  with 'case fields' that have multiple sum values, I want to use these sum values from one table and divide the sum values from the other table to get percentages,I have added a field in one table to store the percentages. 
I am using Iterate Field Values tool to get the output values that I can input into Calculate field to get the percentage, it works but only for the first record, obviously because it is only getting one value from the summary tables, I tried Collect values tool to get multiple values, but I get an error 000539, I using the code from this discussion:
[How to extract multiple values out of a table in ModelBuilder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135712/how-to-extract-multiple-values-out-of-a-table-in-modelbuilder)

[image: Calculate Value]

I have more than than 2 values so I guess List and not index is required.

The whole model runs I get all the results, except the error with collect Value tool. [image: Model]Here is snap shot of the model,
I will separate the iterator tool and add it as submodel once it works.

Here are the input tables and I want to calculate PctCtyPop using calculate field by dividing  the 2 SUM_POPULATION,
[image: calculate field] it giving me the right value for the 1st record 5505/20202 but for the second instead of getting 118774/131506, it is giving some thing else.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the input tables and how you want them to turn out?

Comment: @BERA I have added the 2  tables that I am getting from the two summary statistics and are being used to get PctCtyPop field.

Comment: You talk about "sorting out the iterator" when you get the model fixed, well I suspect that is YOUR problem.Remember EVERYTHING in the model runs as many times as the iterator loops. So your selections that create the summary table will be executed X number of times. I suspect that is NOT what you intended. The Collects tool is being misused, that is for creating a list in a sub-model and passing that list out into a master model, you currently have everything is a single master model. The logic of this model is fundamentally flawed and you need to separate out into sub-models.

Answer (score 1):

I did not need to use Collect Values tool after all, instead I used a spatial join and did a Sum for County population, so that dropped one summary statistics from my previous workflow, I then used Add Join to combine the tables, which made it easier to use Calculate Field tool and I got the results I was looking for. 
Here is model with final changes and the resulting output table with county percentages, within the metropolitan area.[image: Final model]